# Can't recieve emails with Postfix/Dovecot telnet returns status0

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, smtp, dovecot

I try sending emails to my address and I can't find any record of them, even in the logs. I can send to myself on the server just fine.
When I try telneting onto my server I get the following answer

[image]

When I telnet onto port 587 it works as expected.

Within the logs I get

```
warning: unexpected end-of-input from smtp socket while reading input attribute name
smtp socket: wanted attribute: flags
warning: deliver_request_get: error receiving common attributes
```

This is my postconf -M

```
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtp -v
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -v -o syslog_name=postfix/submission -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/let                                                  sencrypt/live/gamesleeve.io/fullchain.pem -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,rej                                                  ect -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
```

this is the postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname,gamesleeve, gamesleeve.io,eiric.com, localhost.members,localhost
mydomain = gamesleeve.io
myhostname = mail.gamesleeve.io
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = gamesleeve.io
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/gamesleeve.io/fullchain.pem
smtp_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/gamesleeve.io/privkey.pem
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/gamesleeve.io/chain.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/gamesleeve.io/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/gamesleeve.io/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_domains = eiric.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

I've doubled checked the MX records and it points to mail.gamesleeve.io with dig

Comment: If your MX record points to mail.gamesleeve.io you should telnet to that DNS name, not to gamesleeve.io. Also check your firewall rules and ``ss -lnt`` to verify the port is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not running an smtp server (`smtpd`). You probably introduced a typo in the first non-comment line of your `master.cf` file.

What it looks like in your case (only looking at the lines starting with smtp):

```
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtp -v
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
```

My defaults were - a **smtp d**aemon is supposed to be started as the inet/smtp service:

```
smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
```

I suspect this happened when you added the non-default `-v` flag. Your `smtpd_banner` indicates you are running Ubuntu, there you should find a template in `/etc/postfix/master.cf.proto` that you can use to compare your edited settings to the distributors defaults.

Comment: OMG that fixed it. Thank you so much!